# Get Access Token to authenticate APIs in Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I already write API in firebase functions which required access token, It's already working with token which I generated using angular web application. But 3rd party service (JAVA) need to access this API,

**Question is how to generate access token from another JAVA application to access this API in firebase function.**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config.firebase);

app.use(validateFirebaseIdToken);
```

Code block in validateFirebaseIdToken method to verifyIDToken.
(This method is use to verify authenticate all the endpoints)

```
    const validateFirebaseIdToken = (req, res, next) => {
        .....
        .......
        .....
        idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];
        .....
        .......
        .....        
        admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then((decodedIdToken) => {
            console.log('ID Token correctly decoded', decodedIdToken);
            req.user = decodedIdToken;
            return next();
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error while verifying Firebase ID token:', error);
            res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
        });
    };
```

Comment: is your java client authenticated with firebase ?

Comment: no, JAVA app also provide API services, there is situation to call firebase API end points trigger some things. 
so JAVA app need to access API in firebase app. still there is no way to authenticate JAVA app/service with firebase app

Comment: ok so basically you want your functions to act as a webhook as well as available as authenticated api points to you angular app ?

Comment: Tried this way, but the generated token isn't valid for firebase function ( token generate from Angualr app is working though)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#generate_an_access_token

Comment: actually angular app directly communicate with real time db using firebase sdk . I wrote this particular end point act as web hook for 3rd party JAVA app/service provider. This API basically store/update particular database records.

Answer (score 0):

Your use case will be a mix of two types of authentications.

In case of Angular App you will have a authenticated user so you can directly write to database with sdk.

For your Java client as you mentioned that you will not have firebase authentication but you still need to call api as authenticated.

I suggest that you skip firebase authentication on the functions endpoint and instead use JWT token as a authentication. This token will be generated one time and stored in your JAVA client (assuming it a server). Each time java send a request this encoded token is send as bearer by client. Then your authentication layer simply user JWT decode instead of firebase id token.

Steps:

1. Generate a JWT token using library : https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken
2. Keep JWT creation token in firebase config.
3. Store generated JWT token in JAVA environment and secure.
4. Authentication layer in firebase will become like this:

   ```
   const validateIdToken = (req, res, next) => {
   idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1];      
   jwt.verify(token, 'YOUR_SECRET', function(err, decoded) {
       if (err){
           console.error('Error while verifying ID token:', err);
          return res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
       }
       console.log(decoded) // bar
       return next();
     });

   };
   ```

You will loose the user information since its a server to server communication.

Comment: According to compliance document we cannot use same token for authenticate it should be refresh (due to man-in-the-middle attack). is there any way to use firebase JAVA SDK to generate firebase access token.

Comment: If you can use Firbase Admin Java SDK in you application, you can directly access database instead of relying on Firebase functions.

Comment: I wanted to keep logics in freebase side and expose interfaces/API to invoke some some database modification, JAVA app/service is a 3rd party in this case. I'm ok with using the SDK for only authentication. I tried below link, but the generated token isn't valid for free-base function (token generates from Angus app is working though)
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth#generate_an_access_token